# How many solutions equation $f(1) = \frac{x}{\sinh x} \int_0^1 \cosh(xy) f(y) dy$ can have?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and consider the following equation
$$
f(1) = \frac{x}{\sinh x} \int_0^1 \cosh(xy) f(y) dy,\tag{1}\label{eq}
$$
where $x \in (0,+\infty)$.
If $f \equiv 0$ the equality is satisfied trivially for every $x$. What can we say for other $x$'s? Specifically:

> Assume that
>   $$
> f(1) \neq \int_0^1 f(y) dy.\tag{2}\label{eq2}
> $$
>   Is it true that for $f \not\equiv 0$, \eqref{eq} is satisfied for at most finitely many $x \in (0,+\infty)$?

As far as I understand, there can not be infinitely many solutions on a given interval $[a,b] \subset (0,+\infty)$, since the right-hand side of \eqref{eq} is an analytic function in $x$, and hence if the equality holds for, say, $x_n \in [a,b]$, then $(x_n)$ has condensation point in $[a,b]$ and the equality holds for every $x \in (0,+\infty)$. This is not possible, since if we let $x \to 0^+$ in \eqref{eq} we get the negation of \eqref{eq2}.

However, I do not know how to show that there are no infinitely many solutions on the *unbounded* interval $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Try showing that as $x \to \infty$, the RHS either increases or decreases without bound (depending on $f$). If either is true, then it can only equal $f(1)$ within some bounded interval.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think the limit at $+\infty$ is exactly $f(1)$. We can split the integral: $\int_0^1 \cosh(xy) f(y) dy = \int_0^\delta + \int_\delta^1$, where $\delta$ is chosen so that $|f(y)-f(1)| < \epsilon$ for $x > \delta$. Then, after multiplying by $x/\sinh x$, the first integral converges to $0$, and the second one to $f(1)$, since $\int_\delta^1 \cosh(xy) f(y) dy = \int_\delta^1 \cosh(xy) (f(y) - f(1)) dy + f(1)x^{-1}(\sinh(x)-\sinh(\delta x))$. Then $|\int_\delta^1 \cosh(xy) (f(y) - f(1)) dy | \le \epsilon x^{-1}(\sinh(x)-\sinh(\delta x))$.

Comment: After some thinking, now I am not so sure that the conjecture is true and the equation may hold for infinitely many $x$'s.

Comment: Yeah, my idea that the integral would grow as $e^x$, balancing $\sinh x$ in the denominator and leaving the $x$ factor unbalanced, wasn't correct. You might check if $f(y) =(1-y)\sin(1/(1 - y))$ provides a counter-example.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks, I will think about that.